# TableView not scroll when keyboard is open for textView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a table view with a textfield and a textview. when Keyboard is open only the textfield move above the keyboard not the textView.

```cs
 public static void HandleKeyboard(this UITableView tableView)
        {
            tableView.KeyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag;

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, null, NSOperationQueue.MainQueue, (notification) =>
            {
                tableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            });

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, null, NSOperationQueue.MainQueue, (notification) =>
            {
                var rect = (notification.UserInfo?[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue)?.CGRectValue ?? CGRect.Empty;
                var bottomInset = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom;
                tableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, rect.Height - bottomInset, 0);
            });
        }
```

[image: when keyboard is open for textfield]

[image]

[image: when keyboard is open for textview]

when I tap Comments textView the keyboard hides the comments textView as shown in images [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtvjnl.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRNgbl.png) but works fine when I tap on textfield, the textfield moves above the keyboard as shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYTQOl.png).

Comment: Hi @mahesh.. Can you share a screenshot of your design? Your question is a bit confusing

Comment: There is easy way to achieve this behaviour by using this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Here is a solution for refer . https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/145121/moving-view-up-when-keyboard-shows